# Fisher's exact test and Bonferroni correction

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, fishers-exact-test, bonferroni

I compared Survivability (live or die) using tibial Intraosseous (io), humerus io, tibial io, intravenous epinephrine for patients who have cardiac arrest.  We had a control group that received no drug.  Do I need to do a Bonferroni correction? .05/5.?

Comment: Can you say a little more about your situation? If your data are just a simple table of counts (or a few tables), can you post your data (or analogous data)?

Comment: If you do pairwise comparisons with the no drug group (io vs no drug, hio vs no drug,...) you have only four comparisons, so Bonferroni would be $\alpha$/4, not /5.

Answer (score 2):

You could use that bonferroni correction but your p-values are correlated. Bonferroni applies regardless as a control on the familywide error rate but the procedure could have poor power (be overly conservative).

Comment: Why the downvote? The answer is a bit terse but is all correct.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand exactly your data set (you should edit and tell us more). Without more information your question looks like a single Fischer exact test on a contingency counting table.

You don't need to adjust for anything if you have a single hypothesis. Adjustment is only necessary if you have multiple comparisons.

However, if you really have multiple hypothesis (not stated in your question clearly), bonferroni is a good candidate because it is simple and your number of tests won't make your detection power too little.